# Plotting Astronomical Data Using Python

Tags: astrophysics, data-analysis, positional-astronomy, python

I have been trying to create a graph which shows the distances between the stars and the earth, yet I could not obtain the desired graph as seen below (click to zoom in):
[image]
My graph:
[image]

As @uhoh suggested, I overlaid one graph on top of the other.
[image]
*I apologize for posting this confusing graph*

The combined graph denotes that the positions of the curves in my graph totally differ from those in the expected graph.

I followed [this guide](http://www.astronexus.com/a-a/motions-long-term) to calculate the position functions of the stars.

**My Question:** Did I made any mistakes that resulted in the anomalies?

*Thanks in advance.*

**Annotations for the Code:**

- Name - Name of the star
- RA - Right Ascension in degrees, ICRS coord. (J2000)
- Dec - Declination in degrees, ICRS coord. (J2000)
- pm_mRA - Proper motion in right ascension, in miliarcseconds per year
- pm_mdec - Proper motion in declination, in miliarcseconds per year
- vr - radial velocity in kilometers per second, a positive value means that the star is moving away from us
- mparallax - parallax of the star in miliarcseconds
- d - distance between the star and the earth

**My Code:**

```
def parseTextFile(file_name, delimiter=",", header=0):
    """ Parse a text file to a list. The file contents are delimited and have a header. """

    with open(file_name) as f:

        # Skip the header
        for i in range(header):
            next(f)


        data = []

        # Parse file contents
        for line in f:

            # Remove the newline char
            line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')

            # Split the line by the delimiter
            line = line.split(delimiter)

            # Strip whitespaces from individual entries in the line
            for i, entry in enumerate(line):
                line[i] = entry.strip()

            # Add the contents of the line to the data list
            data.append(line)

        return data



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot() 

#time span    
time = np.arange(-60000,100000,10)  
count = 1

xdic = {}
ydic = {}
zdic = {}

#multiple lines of data
for star in parseTextFile(file_name, header=1):

    name = str(star[0])
    RA = float(star[1])
    Dec = float(star[2])
    pm_mRA = float(star[3])
    pm_mDec = float(star[4])
    vr = float(star[5])
    mparallax = float(star[6])

    pm_RA = pm_mRA * 0.001
    pm_Dec = pm_mDec * 0.001
    d = 1 / (mparallax * 0.001)

    #Transverse velocities
    vta = pm_RA * d * 4.740
    vtd = pm_Dec * d * 4.740

    #Linear velocities
    vx = vr * np.cos(Dec) * np.cos(RA) - vta * np.sin(RA) - vtd * np.sin(Dec) * np.cos(RA) 
    vy = vr * np.cos(Dec) * np.sin(RA) + vta * np.cos(RA) - vtd * np.sin(Dec) * np.sin(RA)
    vz = vr * np.sin(Dec) + vtd * np.cos(Dec)

    #unit conversion from km/s to pc/year
    vx_pcyr = vx / 977780
    vy_pcyr = vy / 977780
    vz_pcyr = vz / 977780

    #initial positions
    xi = d * np.cos(Dec) * np.cos(RA)
    yi = d * np.cos(Dec) * np.sin(RA)
    zi = d * np.sin(Dec)

    #position functions
    x = xi + vx_pcyr * time
    y = yi + vy_pcyr * time
    z = zi + vz_pcyr * time

    distance = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2)

    ax.plot(time,distance,label=name)


ax.set_xlabel('Time (Year)')
ax.set_ylabel('Distance (pc)')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is well written, but I wonder what kind of answer you are expecting? What makes you think your plot might be incorrect? Try this: plot using the same units and scale as the original (0.0 to 10.0 *light years*) using the correct conversion factor and `ax.set_ylim(0.0, 10.0)` then save a copy with a transparent background with `plt.savefig('mytransparentplot', transparent=True)` and overlay it on the original (in powerpoint or any image manipulating tool) and stretch it and see if it overlays perfectly. Or *print out some distances* numerically and ask how to check those

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question which remains unsolved.

Comment: did you convert the units of your plot from parsec to light years before overlaying?

Comment: If you solve the problem it's perfectly fine to post a short answer and to click "accept". No need to close it, the problem has been solved. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming question and does not invoke or require astronomical information.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot changing the unit of the distance from parsec to light year.
This is a simple unit conversion error which should have been avoided.

**Ultimate Graph:**
[image]

**Data Used:**

> Name,RA(deg),Dec(deg),pm_RA(mas/yr),pm_Dec(mas/yr),Vr(km/s),parallax(mas)
>   Wolf 359,164.120271,+07.014658,-3842.0,-2725.0,19.321,418.3
>   Proxima Centauri,217.42895219,-62.67948975,-3775.75,765.54,-22.40,768.13
>   Alpha Centauri,219.900850,-60.835619,-3608,686,-22.3,742
>   Barnard's star,269.45207511,+04.69339088,-798.58,10328.12,-110.51,548.31
>   Gliese 445,176.92240640,+78.69116300,743.61,481.40,-111.65,186.86
>   Luhman 16A,150.8218675,-53.319405556,-2754.77,358.72,23.1,500.51
>   Sirius,101.28715533,-16.71611586,-546.01,-1223.07,-5.50,379.21
>   Lalande 21185,165.83414166,+35.96988004,-580.27,-4765.85,-84.69,392.64
>   Ross 248,355.479122,+44.177994,115.10,-1592.77,-77.715,316.7
>   Gliese 65,24.756054,-17.950569,3321,562,29,373.70

**Code:**

```
%matplotlib qt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches


def parseTextFile(file_name, delimiter=",", header=0):
    """ Parse a text file to a list. The file contents are delimited and have a header. """

    with open(file_name) as f:

        # Skip the header
        for i in range(header):
            next(f)


        data = []

        # Parse file contents
        for line in f:

            # Remove the newline char
            line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')

            # Split the line by the delimiter
            line = line.split(delimiter)

            # Strip whitespaces from individual entries in the line
            for i, entry in enumerate(line):
                line[i] = entry.strip()

            # Add the contents of the line to the data list
            data.append(line)

        return data


if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_name = 'C:\\Users\\The Wings of Dream\\Desktop\\UWO-PA-Python-Course\\Lecture 5\\Homework 2\\star_data.txt'


#Program Begin:  


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212) 

time = np.arange(-60000,100000,10)  
count = 1

xdic = {}
ydic = {}
zdic = {}


for star in parseTextFile(file_name, header=1):

    name = str(star[0])
    RA = float(star[1])
    Dec = float(star[2])
    pm_mRA = float(star[3])
    pm_mDec = float(star[4])
    vr = float(star[5])
    mparallax = float(star[6])

    pm_RA = pm_mRA * 0.001
    pm_Dec = pm_mDec * 0.001
    d = 1 / (mparallax * 0.001)

    vta = pm_RA * d * 4.740
    vtd = pm_Dec * d * 4.740

    vx = vr * np.cos(Dec) * np.cos(RA) - vta * np.sin(RA) - vtd * np.sin(Dec) * np.cos(RA) 
    vy = vr * np.cos(Dec) * np.sin(RA) + vta * np.cos(RA) - vtd * np.sin(Dec) * np.sin(RA)
    vz = vr * np.sin(Dec) + vtd * np.cos(Dec)

    vx_pcyr = vx / 977780
    vy_pcyr = vy / 977780
    vz_pcyr = vz / 977780

    xi = d * np.cos(Dec) * np.cos(RA)
    yi = d * np.cos(Dec) * np.sin(RA)
    zi = d * np.sin(Dec)

    x = xi + vx_pcyr * time
    y = yi + vy_pcyr * time
    z = zi + vz_pcyr * time

    xdic['x'+str(count)] = x
    ydic['y'+str(count)] = y
    zdic['z'+str(count)] = z

    distance = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) * 3.26156

    ax1.plot(xdic['x'+str(count)],ydic['y'+str(count)],zdic['z'+str(count)])
    ax2.plot(time,distance,label=name)

    count = count + 1

w_oort, h_oort = 160000, 3.2
ax2.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((-60000, 0.03), w_oort,h_oort,color='slateblue',alpha=0.2))
ax2.annotate('Oort Cloud', xy=(15000,1.6), size=12)

plt.axvline(x=0,color='gray',linestyle='--',linewidth='0.5')

#plotting constraints
ax2.set_ylim(0.0, 10.0)
ax2.set_xlim(-60000, 100000)

ax1.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax1.set_zlabel('z axis')
ax1.title.set_text('Motion of Stars in Space')
ax2.title.set_text('Distance-Time')
ax2.set_xlabel('Time (Year)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Distance (Light Year)')
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
```

ax1 subplot will give you a 3d parametricplot showing the motion of the stars.

Comment: Happy ending to an interesting story! I think the plot *and the original data* is really interesting, and adding and accepting an answer rather than closing it will probably allow more people to see it.

Comment: It's also okay to click "accept" on your own answer

Comment: Okay, but the system tells me that I can accept my answer tomorrow.